# How to update Azure Devops Test case results from Specflow Feature

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation, azure-devops, specflow

I have created a test case in Azure Devops as follows. You can see the test plan ID, test suite ID in the below screenshot. My issue is, I want to update the test result in Azure, when I run the test cases from my local file using specflow. How can I implement that ? Now the test case is showing 'Manual'. I want to make it automated and show the pass/fail result when I run it from my local machine/cloud. Please help.
[azure structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT3Gd.png)

My specflow feature file look like this.
[feature file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQuGO.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Copy the code and paste it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

> How to update Azure Devops Test case results from Specflow Feature

You could use the SpecSync for Azure DevOps, which is a synchronization tool that synchronizes Given/When/Then-based BDD scenarios to Azure DevOps.

From [official link](https://www.specsolutions.eu/services/specsync/):

> **Is it possible to synchronize SpecFlow scenarios to existing Azure DevOps Test Cases?**
>
> Yes. If you synchronize a test case which does not have a test case
>   tag yet, SpecSync will create a new one and tags the scenario. But if
>   you add the test case tag manually (in the format of @tc:123),
>   referring to an existing test case in Azure DevOps, SpecSync will
>   update that test case at the next synchronization.

More details about the detail tutorials please take a look at [this document](https://specsolutions.gitbook.io/specsync/getting-started/getting-started-specflow) and [here](https://specsolutions.gitbook.io/specsync/important-concepts/synchronizing-automated-test-cases):

> Besides tracking the test results, the test cases can be marked as
>   "**Automated**", although test results can also be registered to a
>   non-automated test case as well.

Hope this helps.